# What is the proper way of downsampling a time series containing percentage data?

Tags: statistics, time-series

I have a collection of CPU utilization, the metric is percentage (%). The sample is taken every 10 seconds. I need to use 1 minute resolution data for a calculation. What is the best way of downsampling percentage? The data looks like this:

```
[5 6 10 5 3 12 10]
```

I need to generate a single number out of this that represents the CPU utilization for that minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the best way is to calculate the average.